# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to create to a one-to-many relationship between models `Post` and `Category` but I get

> `` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `school`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade) ``

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->string('title')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreign_key` field and your `id` should be of the same type, for example, if `categories.id` is `bigIncrements`, your `foreign_key` inside your `Post table` also should be `bigInteger`.

**Category Table**

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Post Table**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('title')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Note**: You should make sure, your **Category Table** migration is running before **Post Table** migration.

Comment: I don't think it is wise to suggest `->onDelete('cascade')` for the `category_id`. Just because a _category_ is deleted doesn't necessarily mean that all related _posts_ should disappear as well.

Comment: That is not a problem, it is rare that `category` will be deleted and all the related posts also will be deleted.

Comment: @hadayatullah-sarwary, Well if you didn't know, that is what `cascade` basically does.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa If a record is deleted, all the sub_records of that records will be deleted from other tables.

Comment: @Hedayatullah Sarwary Thanks, the problem is that the Post table migrated before Category table as you said I reverse the order then migrate without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$table->id();` creates an `unSignedBigInteger` ***(UNSIGNED BIGINT)***.

`$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();` creates an `unSignedInteger`. ***(UNSIGNED INTEGER)***.

### Fix

```php
// Instead of:
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned(); ❌

// Use this:
$table->unsignedBigInteger("category_id")->nullable(); ✅

$table->foreign("category_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("categories")
                ->onDelete("set null");
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete Foreign Key Contsraints  From bottom of your table

Please see a screenshot
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Ic2.png)